# My PS4 account was attached to a Gmail that was hacked. How can I recover my PS4 account?

Tags: ps4

I had my Gmail hacked recently, and I had to switch my gmail, but I forgot to change my PlayStation network Gmail account. Now it locked me out of my games and won't let me play them unless I verify myself with my previous email.

How would I fix this?

Comment: can you not go through Google's account recovery process on your original Gmail?

Comment: no it wont even show my previous email now

Comment: Have you spoken to the PS Support?

Answer (score 2):

thanks to Ben I figured out how to fix this problem. but I didn't call them since its a harder hastle to anyways. I went to the official PlayStation website and went to PlayStation chat support where a live agent helped me resolve this solution. I recommend going there for all PS4 help since they were very helpful and decriptive.